# Im getting a Syntax error in Jquery/Ajax code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

***There is an error in the code 
syntax error***

```
    $(function(){
            $("#users").on("change", function(e){

               /* values from select statement and assigning to a variable*/
                var $filter = $("#users").val();

                $.ajax({
                   /*sending variable to the controller */
                    url: "finance/finance_transaction/",

                    data: {filter: $filter},/* variable */ 
                    dataType: "html" 

                    }).done(function(msg){

                    }).fail({});
             )}; /*syntax error points here */
        )};
```

it takes values from the select statement and sends it to the controller

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: thnx it was the brackets that was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#users").on("change", function(e){
        // ...valid code, skipped... 
    )}; /*syntax error points here */
)};
```

The braces don't match up. Like HTML tags, whichever you opened first must be closed last. The last two rows should be:

```
    });
});
```

Comment: thnx i chnged nw im getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $filer is not defined "

Comment: @Usuf There is no `$filer` identifier in the posted code. There is `$filter` though!

Answer (score 0):

Your closing braces makes the issue

```
$(function(){
            $("#users").on("change", function(e){

               /* values from select statement and assigning to a variable*/
                var $filter = $("#users").val();

                $.ajax({
                   /*sending variable to the controller */
                    url: "finance/finance_transaction/",

                    data: {filter: $filter},/* variable */ 
                    dataType: "html" 

                    }).done(function(msg){

                    }).fail({});
            }); /*corrected here */
        });   /*corrected here */
```

Comment: if u can help me with this error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: $filer is not defined "

Comment: There is no such variable, $filter. You want to define it first.